# How can I redirect the powershell output to my tcl-file?

Tags: batch-file, redirect, tcl

Inside a **.tcl** file the batch file **"test.ps1"** is executed.

```
    set output [exec test.ps1]
    puts $output
```

**Edit:**

When I simply execute directly the test.ps1 file I can see all outputs in a shell-window. If I call the .tcl file I do **not** see the output only at the end when the batch file finished. All output text is written at the end but **not** updated when the ps1-file is still running.

What I see is that the application, where the .tcl file is called, goes to a "freeze" state so it is not possible to use that GUI as long the .ps1 file is running. At the end of the ps1 file all output is written at once and I can use the application again.

**Question:**
Is there a way to continously update the shell window in order to see the output?

Comment: Why are you calling a batch file to call a PowerShell script, why not calling the latter directly?

Comment: is possible... but I also do not see any output..! So it is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command in background using `&` and redirect its output to the tcl script output using `>@stdout`:

```
exec test.ps1 >@stdout &
```

Check [the Tcl exec docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/exec.htm) for details on how this works.

Comment: when I use: set exec C:/temp/test.ps1 >@stdout &    I get following errors: Error:wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
Error:    while executing

Comment: @Norick do `exec test.ps1 >@stdout &` without the `set`

Comment: then I get this error message: Error:channel "stdin" wasn't opened for writing while executing

Comment: @Norick Not sure why. I'd post another question about that error message.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
################################################################################
##### Calls a single Powershell command (blocking, hidden)
### Arg: The command to give to Powershell via -command switch
### Ret: A List of three elements:
###  -1 "" <errtext>       -> error from twapi::create_process
###   0 <stdouttxt> ""     -> Ok
###   1 "..." <stderrtext> -> Maybe Ok, something written to stderr
#
proc execPowershellCmd {cmd} {
     set cmd "-command $cmd"
     foreach chan {stdin stdout stderr} {
             lassign [chan pipe] rd$chan wr$chan
     }
     if {[catch {
        set cmd [string map [list \" \\\"] $cmd]; # muss noch in Wiki...
        twapi::create_process [auto_execok powershell] -cmdline $cmd -showwindow hidden \
         -inherithandles 1 -stdchannels [list $rdstdin $wrstdout $wrstderr]
     } ret]} {
        return [list -1 "" $ret]
     }
     chan close $wrstdin; chan close $rdstdin; chan close $wrstdout; chan close $wrstderr
     foreach chan [list $rdstdout $rdstderr] {
             chan configure $chan -encoding cp850 -blocking true; # -buffering full?; # -enc?
     }
     set out [read $rdstdout]; set err [read $rdstderr]
     chan close $rdstdout; chan close $rdstderr
     return [list [string compare $err ""] $out $err]
}
```